# How to install a .sty file on Texmaker

Tags: packages, installing, texmaker

I'm quite new to LaTeX, so please take that in consideration when answering my question. Thank you.

So I want to install `ans.sty`, but I'm not quite sure how to do so. I'm using TexMaker and I've tried `usepackage`, but appearantly that doesn't work. From what I read here, I need to manually install it, but I've been unable to do so. It seems I need to find a texfm directory on my Windows, but I coudn't find it.

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

You should install `ans.sty` in your local TeXMF root, say  `TeXMFLocal\tex\latex\ans` and the documentation in `TeXMFLocal\doc\latex\ans`. If you're under MiKTEX, you also should create the local root, with `MiKTeX Settings`, `Roots` tab, and refreshh the FNDB (File Names Data Base).

Answer (score 0):

My solution only works for packages that are available in the repository: If you're using MiKTEX, you could consider using a package that is available by default, e.g. `answers` (it's also 20 years more recently updated, which could be a consideration). If your setup installs missing files on the fly, it will automatically install it for you. Alternatively, use the MiKTEX Package Manager to manually install and update packages.